# Resize UIView height based on UILabel text in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

So I have a simple `UIView` with a `UILabel` contained within. Currently, the height of the `UIView` is hardcoded which is an issue when the `UILabel` text is so long enough for the content to require more height than the `UIView` provides.

Is there a simple method to calculate the appropriate height for the `UIView` in order to show all the content in the contained `UILabel`?

Thank you!

Comment: Autolayout is your friend

Comment: How can autolayout help me in this case? The UILabel text varies in length.

Answer (score 14):

**If you are using auto layout:**
You just need to pin leading, trailing, top and bottom of your UILabel to its superview (leading, trailing, top and bottom).
Set the `numberOfLines` property to 0, that means how many you need.
Now you can decide to constraint the width of your UIlabel instance to a specific number or set the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`, basically you are saying that you want your label to create another line if the text is bigger than this width.
Now it comes the magic of layout, each view has an `intrinsicContentSize` property, on `UILabel` it correspond to the size occupied by the text. This makes the `UILabel` "push" its superview bounds to adapt to its content size.
Of course the superview must not have any constraints in height.

**If you are not using auto layout:**
 After setting the text you can send the label the `- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size` method by setting a fixed width and `CGFLOAT_MAX` in height, it will return the size occupied by the full text thus you cab set the superview frame accordingly.

Comment: Great one! Thank a lot. This saved my hours!!

Comment: @Andrea, bro could you please take a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46034278/how-to-adjust-uiview-height-according-to-the-collection-view-content-height-in-s ?