# How to adjust UIView height according to the Collection View Content Height in swift 3?

Tags: swift3, uiview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a problem of adjusting the UIView height in my project. I illustrated the project.

[image]

Let me explain about my project image.
Each Orange UIView has **trailing, leading , top and bottom constraints** and **vertical spacing** to each UIView. 
 But, I add "Height" to each UIView because if I don't add, it gives error and add the "Height" warning. 
In UIView2, I add 3 Container Views. Each Container Views has 3 View Controllers. (Data 1 View, Data 2 View, Data 3 View) 
I embed Collection View inside in each views. 
The problem is that in Data 3 View has many collection View cell data. So, the height of Orange UIView should be increase according to the collection view content. 
Currently, I just add fixed height constant (height:800) if users click on the Data 3 segmented control button. 
 But, I don't want to set fixed height like this. 
I've been trying to solve this problem since last week. I could not solve this till now. 
Can anyone help me explain in step by step please? Because I have no idea of what should I do.

Comment: Why don't you make outlet of your height constraint and change its constant via code? It will be dynamic. Constraint to content size is difficult in the storyboard.

Comment: I don't want to make constant height because I could not tell the exact data count that will contain in collection view. If I define height constant = 400, but the data count increase from server, then I need to redefine the height again.

Comment: How will you add a constraint with content size??

Comment: I just add height constant of view controller.

Comment: so, you want to increase the height of your collection view depending on its content size. and accordingly view 2 should also increase its height. but, you also want view number 3 to stay fully visible on the screen. so you also need view 2 to have a maximum height. Did I exactly discribe your problem?

Comment: @hasan83, View 1 and 2 has no problem. Only view 3 has many data content. So, we need to adjust the height. But, I solved with same height to other view 1 and 2 and set enable the scroll for view 3 bro.

Answer (score 0):

Since `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` inherit from `UIScrollView` they basically do not have an `intrinsicContentSize`.
You have two ways to make the same height as the content size (the space that you can scroll):

- You can subclass the collection view and override `intrinsicContentSize` method to return the `contentSize` and the `sizeThatFits:` method as well
- Create a height constraint in the interface and set it as equal to the content size of the collection view.