# Resize UIView based on UILabel height

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uilabel

I saw some similar answers, but my question is slightly different. I want to create view that have height `greaterThanOrEqualToConstant` and put `UILabel` inside it with top left alignment (`constraint` to `top`). If text of `UILabel` have only 1 line, I want to keep size of `UIView` greater that some constant, but if text have 2,3,4.. etc lines (`greaterThatConstant`), I want to resize this view based on label height.

Comment: Possible Duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35596058/resize-uiview-height-based-on-uilabel-text-in-swift

Comment: @Den Andreychuk Please check my updated answer. and let me know if any issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize UIView height based on UILabel text in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35596058/resize-uiview-height-based-on-uilabel-text-in-swift)

Comment: Refer this video i hope its enough for you to get solution https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ST1lnu_ZWI

Answer (score 0):

You can use constraint priorities for this. In order to let view "grow", you specify smaller priority to container view height and then label's bottom constraint (distance to container view's bottom) is greater or equal than whatever value you are using. Took a little fiddling with when I first needed this feature :)

Answer (score 0):

**FOR VIEW CONSTRAINTS:**

CHECK IMAGE. :
[image]

**FOR LABEL CONSTRAINTS:**

CHECK IMAGE. : 
[image]

**CODE**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    let subview = UIView()
    subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(subview)

    //SET VIEW Constarins
    subview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
    subview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 25).isActive = true
    subview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: 25).isActive = true



    let lblValue = UILabel()
    lblValue.text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum"
    lblValue.numberOfLines = 0
    lblValue.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    lblValue.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    subview.addSubview(lblValue)

    //SET LABEL Constarins
    lblValue.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subview.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    lblValue.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subview.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    lblValue.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subview.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    lblValue.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subview.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Comment: Hey @DenAndreychuk let me know if above code is working or not ?